# Dragonboard 8094 | Android L | application fails PIE check

Tags: android, security, makefile, android-5.0-lollipop, dragonboard

I have a Dragonboard 8094 (Snapdragon 810) that came with Android L pre-loaded.

I'm trying to run the calculator sample application that came with the Hexagon SDK v1.2.2, however it seems to be slightly out-dated.

Android L introduced some new security measures, including a PIE (Position-independent executables) check for all binaries. When I try to run the calculator binary on the dragonboard I get the following error:

```
error: only position independent executables (PIE) are supported.
```

I can't rebuild Android to disable the PIE check because the source code from Intrystic will not able available until the end of February.

Is there a way to modify the makefile of the calculator example to build a position-independent executable.

Is there anything else that I can do?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines in Android.mk and recompile the sample application may solve your problem.

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -pie -fPIE
LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -pie -fPIE
```